# Which athletes were the first to break the color barriers in hockey?

Tags: ice-hockey, history

Ice hockey, by nature of being a sport developed by [British colonialists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_hockey#History), has largely been made up of teams of people who can trace their ancestry to the British isles, the Nordic regions of Europe, or European Russians.

However, Canada and the United States have become increasingly diverse nations over the last 60 years or so.

Which players were among the first to break color barriers in ice hockey? I'm referring to the ice hockey equivalents of [Jackie Robinson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackie_Robinson) or [Masanori Murakami](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masanori_Murakami), or [Steve Bellán](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Bell%C3%A1n).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a timeline of some of the notable milestones:

**1948:** [Larry Kwong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Kwong) appears for the New York Rangers; he was the son of **Chinese** immigrants to Canada.

[image: Larry Kwong]

**1958:** [Willie O'Ree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willie_O%27Ree), playing for the Boston Bruins, is the first **black** player to play in the NHL. He has been called the Jackie Robinson of the NHL.

[image: Willie O'Ree]

**1989:** [Robin Bawa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_Bawa), the first **Indian** player, joins the Washington Capitals.

[image: Robin Bawa]

**1989:** [Bill Guerin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Guerin) becomes the first **Hispanic** player in the NHL. One of the top scorers ever in the league, he will likely be elected to the Hall of Fame as soon as he is eligible. He won two Stanley Cups in his 18-year career, during which he played for eight different teams.

[image: Bill Guerin]

**1990:** [Jim Paek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Paek) is the first **Korean** player, playing for the Pittsburgh Penguins and eventually winning two Stanley Cups with them.

[image: Jim Paek]

**1994:** [Paul Kariya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Kariya) is the first player of **Japanese** descent as he joins the Anaheim Mighty Ducks, and later becomes the first player of Asian descent to score 50 goals in a season.

[image: Paul Kariya]

**2003:** [Jordin Tootoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordin_Tootoo) is the first **Inuit** player in the league. He is still playing for the Nashville Predators as of this writing.

[image: Jordin Tootoo]

---

#### Other Sources

[Willie O'Rea, Hockey Pioneer](http://bruins.nhl.com/ext/pdfs/Willie_O%27Ree.pdf) [pdf]
[List of ice hockey players of Asian descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ice_hockey_players_of_Asian_descent)
[List of ice hockey players of Middle Eastern descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ice_hockey_players_of_Middle_Eastern_descent) (not used as categorization is difficult)

Comment: Technically *I* didn't, but they're there all the same...

Comment: Fine, all the love to @edmastermind29 :P

Comment: @Aarthi freely received...freely given :D

Answer (score 4):

Willie O'Ree is the considered the first African American to play professionally in the NHL. He was a right winger on the Boston Bruins during the 1957-58 and 1960-61 seasons. He didn't see much playing time after the 1957-58 season due to an eye injury resulting in 95% blindness in his right eye.

[image]

Go Bruins!