# What factors should I consider toward keeping sports cards in mint condition?

Tags: maintenance, collectibles, cards

I once collected sports cards.

My means to store sports cards were to slip the card into a soft-sleeve cover, whether in a binder or a plastic bin made for card collecting. For "more valuable" cards (ie. rookie cards), I would slip the soft-sleeve covered card into a hard-sleeve cover.

I have taken a look at different grading scales for the condition of sports cards, and one thing seems to be common in card collecting...a card that is graded as "near perfect" is known to be in "mint" condition.

[One grading scale](http://www.sgccard.com/grading_scale.htm) grades a card in "mint" condition as a 96/100.

> A minor flaw may exist upon close examination.

[Another grading scale](http://www.baseballcards101.com/graded-cards.htm) grades a card in "mint" condition as a 9/10.

> ...a superb condition card that exhibits only one ... minor [flaw]

**What factors should I consider toward keeping sports cards in mint condition?**

Comment: Interesting - in my mind this is off-topic for Sports SE because, although there is a slight connection to sports, the answer and question could be applied to cards of other themes. The difficulty is that I don't see any other obvious SE site where it would belong, and it seems a reasonable question. It would probably fit best on the proposed [Collectors & Collections](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48472/collectors-collections) SE site - which isn't much help, since it's still in the definition phase.

Comment: @edmastermind29, I'm not sure about, but it is not about sports.

Comment: @Spinner 1) proposed vs. beta 2) I debate that sports cards are different in that there is a fanbase dedicated to sports cards, and the sites I reference are specifically for the grading of sports cards.

Comment: @SportsFan Okay. Just trying out a question about a new topic. However, I do debate that a question about sports "on all levels" would include collecting...if we also include [sports media](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/media), [sports history](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1490/which-athletes-were-the-first-to-break-the-color-barriers-in-hockey), and [sports theories](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/163/what-factors-give-a-home-advantage-and-how-big-is-it), what's wrong with sports collectibles?

Comment: [Meta](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/396/sports-collectibles-on-topic-for-sports-se) discussion here.

Comment: This is very much on topic as a part of sports fandom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Moisture** is obviously a major factor. Keep them away from any water source, or out of a basement.

Also **sunlight**, as that will cause the color of the cards to fade. Although if they are in a box that is not an issue.

**Be careful of the corners.** Make sure they do not get bent, ripped, or warped in any manor, as that will seriously detract from your overall value.

You seem to know what you are doing with these and have taken the necessary steps to keep your cards safe.